# Validate fileupload with command object in grails

Tags: grails

I have a domain class with profile pic as field.

```
class Doctor {
String name
byte[] profilePic
}
```

I'm uploading a file from my gsp

```
  <input name="profilePic" type="file" />
```

I'm validating the inputs using command object using cmd.hasErorrs() in my controller. This understandably gives a type mismatch validation error.

How to use the command object in this case?

Comment: your should map profilePic field to return a path rather than bytes by using something like var filePath=$('#fileUpload').val();. Also, your form type should be multipart.

Comment: REMEMBER! Save bytes in DB it's very-very-very bad implementation. Better save on server/pc, more better save in cloud.